# Why use Base64?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, base64

Base64 encoding increases the size of the input by around 37% when sent over the wire. If this is the case, why not use UTF-8 to encode the contents(say a .jpg file). This way the size of the file does not increase right?

eg: If I want to send the string "asd", a UTF-8 encoded version of this will be **3 bytes**, whereas a Base64 encoded version will be **4 bytes**.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of Base64 is to allow binary data to be transferred over a communication channel that cannot be relied on to transfer all possible byte values end-to-end.  In particular, Base64 is used where byte values between 128 and 255 cannot be easily and reliably transferred.

In contrast, UTF-8 is used to encode Unicode across a channel that *can* be assumed to reliably transfer all possible byte values end-to-end (sometime referred to as an "8-bit clean" channel).

So, you have two problems with your proposal.  First, a JPEG is binary data, not Unicode, so UTF-8 isn't really appropriate:  if you "encode a JPEG as UTF-8" in the obvious way (treating the JPEG as a sequence of bytes, each associated with a Unicode code point from U+00 to U+FF, and then encoding those code points as UTF-8), it will double the size of all byte values from 128-255, so you'll have, on average, a 50% increase in file size.  Second, even if you did this, the resulting encoded JPEG would require a communication channel that's 8-bit clean, so it couldn't be used in situations where Base64 is needed anyway.

Edit: In a comment, you asked if we couldn't use "input binary -> 7 bit ASCII encoding -> send over wire" to save space.  I assume you mean taking the input binary as a long stream of bits and chopping them up into 7-bit chunks and sending those as ASCII?  Yes, that could be done and would only increase size by 14%, but it's not *just* the non-ASCII byte values 128-255 that cause problems.  In MIME email, where Base64 is most frequently used, differences in line-ending convention (carriage return, line feed, or a combination) from platform to platform, certain historical line length restrictions enshrined in the standards, and so on mean that not all ASCII characters (bytes 0-127) can be safely used.  Base64 is not the best trade-off possible between compatibility and efficiency, but it's pretty close.

Comment: What is the exact process in converting a JPEG file(binary data) before being sent over the wire? I assumed it was (input binary) --> 8bit ASCII --> Base64 encoded string --> finally sent as binary over the wire.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as "8bit ASCII"; ASCII is a 7-bit encoding.  So, it's just "input binary (with any byte values allowed) -> Base64 encoding -> output binary (with only a subset of byte values allowed)".  Actually, in this case, the output binary is also ASCII, so you could write "output ASCII" instead.

Comment: If we go like this: "input binary -> 7 bit ASCII encoding -> send over wire", we can reduce the increase in size overhead right?

Comment: @user3282666 "converting a JPEG file(binary data) before being sent over the wire": It depends on the context. In HTTP, the bytes can be sent as is, after a header that says the body is a JPEG, and optionally specifying the number of bytes.

Comment: 2 parts of this answer don't make sense to me. (1) You say values 128-255 would be doubled in size. Why? Isn't the point of UTF-8 to make 255 chars fit in 8 bytes? U+00 to U+FF is 255 possibilities. (2) You imply that communication channels aren't "8-bit clean". What does this mean and why wouldn't they be this way? Don't we send data as bytes?

Comment: (1) In UTF-8, code points 128-255 are each encoded as two bytes, of the form `1100001x 10xxxxxx`. where the seven "x"s are the least significant bits of the original code point.

Comment: (2) While a particular channel might consist of a stream of bytes, the communication protocols in place don't necessarily allow a particular chunk of "data" to consist of unrestricted byte sequences.  For example, the standard protocols for the transfer of email require the body of the message to consist of US-ASCII text only with lines no more than 998 characters each terminated by CR LF and with no isolated occurrences of the CR and LF characters.  This channel isn't 8-bit clean, since arbitrary binary data can't be sent unencoded in the body w/o risk of rejection or corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is usually used in instances to represent arbitrary binary data in a text format, it has a 33.3'% overhead but that's better than say hex notation which has a 50% overhead.
utf-8 is a text encoding which cannot represent arbitrary binary data which is what a jped file is.
There is little to no reason to convert the binary data to text to transfer it over the wire so a many times people do it because they don't know any better.
The only reason to use it is if you get it from apis or libraries.

Comment: "Base64 is usually used in instances to represent arbitrary binary data in a text format". But in the end the text is also sent as 0s and 1s over the wire. What I thought is to avoid the 33% overhead, when there is an arbitrary binary data as input take each 8 bits and encode it to the corresponding ASCII character, instead of taking 6 bits and encoding. This way we can avoid the increase in size. Is this not right?

Comment: Are you assuming that base64 is some standard for encoding data before sending it *over the wire*. I'm not really sure what you're trying to figure out. Also ascii is 7bit.

Comment: Yeah Ascii is 7 bit. My bad. Base64 is a standard used in many places to encode images before being sent. If it causes a significant increase in size, then why use it? I assumed the conversion works like this: (input binary) --> ASCII --> Base64 encoded string--> send over wire. Instead if we use: (input binary) --> ASCII --> send over wire, we don't have the increase in size overhead.

Comment: *Base64 is a standard used in many places to encode images before being sent.* This was done long ago send to files via AJAX, it is not needed anymore since now ajax supports  file upload. So we do (input binary) -> sent over the wire (no transforming of the data).

Comment: You may find the following Wikipedia link helpful to explain some of these concepts: [Binary to text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).  Note that Base64 is used for encoding images sent in email, but that's about it.  This is done for both historical and legitimate compatibility reasons -- many email systems would mangle attachments if they were sent in "pure binary".  Web servers *could* technically send images in Base64 but never do -- they just send the raw binary stream.

Comment: Yes, email uses Base64 for encoding images. Instead of encoding every **3 bytes** as **4bytes** (which is what Base64 does), why not just send the 3 bytes?

Comment: Okay I got it. I guess the reason for encoding every 3 bytes into 4 bytes is because not all characters in the ASCII character set are treated as the same by all computers. eg: the ASCII character 10 (for line break) is not treated the same by all systems. To avoid this discrepancy in processing of certain ASCII characters, we use a subset of the ASCII set. The subset has only 64 characters and there is no confusion amongst different systems on how to handle these 64 characters.